# Find the closest average of three numbers - code optimization

Tags: r

This may seem trivial, but I have a code that finds the average of the closest two numbers in a set of three numbers. So 5 examples:

```
x1 <- c(1,5,7)
x2 <- c(NA,2,3)
x3 <- c(2,6,4)
x4 <- c(1,NA,NA)
x5 <- c(1,3,1)
```

I would get an output of

```
y1 = 6
y2 = 2.5
y3 = 4
y4 = 1
y5 = 1
```

respectively. Basically, finding the closest 2 numbers, then averaging them, accounting for NA and ties.

This code is a monstrosity:

```
x <-x[!is.na(x)]
x <-x[order(x)]
y <-ifelse(length(x) == 1, x, 
      ifelse(length(x) == 2, mean(x), 
        ifelse(length(x) == 3, 
          ifelse(abs(x[1] - x[2]) == abs(x[2] - x[3]), mean(x), 
            ifelse(abs(x[1] - x[2]) > abs(x[2] - x[3]), mean(x[2:3]),
              ifelse(abs(x[1] - x[2]) < abs(x[2] - x[3]), mean(x[1:2]), 
     "error"))), NA)))
```

It works, but because this is part of a larger `for` loop, I was wondering there's a better way of doing this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define an S3 generic with `"list"` and `"default"` methods.

The `"default"` method takes a vector and sort it (which also removes NA values) and then if the length of what is left is <= 1 it returns the single value or NA if none.  If the length is 2 or the two successive differences are the same then it returns the mean of all values; otherwise, it finds the index of the first of the pair of the closest two values and returns the mean of the values.

The `"list"` method applies the default method repeatedly.

```
mean_min_diff <- function(x) UseMethod("mean_min_diff")

mean_min_diff.list <- function(x) sapply(x, mean_min_diff.default)

mean_min_diff.default <- function(x) {
  x0 <- sort(x)
  if (length(x0) <= 1) c(x0, NA)[1]
  else if (length(x0) == 2 || sd(diff(x0)) == 0) mean(x0)
  else mean(x0[seq(which.min(diff(x0)), length = 2)])
}
```

Now test it out:

```
mean_min_diff(x1)
## [1] 6

mean_min_diff(list(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5))
## [1] 6.0 2.5 4.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: yes, but that's not what the OP's doing: `abs(x[1] - x[2]) == abs(x[2] - x[3]), mean(x)`

Comment: OK. Have revised.